# Remove $ sign in Sheets using script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that I have copied values only.

I need a script that remove the $ sign from a specific tab.

This formula is not working:

```
function ToNumber(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("SF load copy");
  sheetName.setNumberFormat("0.00"); 

}
```

getting the following error:
TypeError: sheetName.setNumberFormat is not a functionDetails

Would you be able to help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a range that the number formatting will be applied to.

For example:

```js
function ToNumber(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("SF load copy");
  var range = sheetName.getRange('A1:A20');
  range.setNumberFormat("0.00");
}
```